# Using source command in script but defining the input file in the command line of a terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, source

I have a script at the moment that reads in variables and then operates on them like the following;

```
#!bin/bash
a=10
b=15
c=20

d=a*b+c
echo $d
```

However I would like to split this up into an input file containing:

```
a=10
b=15
c=20
```

and a script which does the operation

```
#!/bin/bash
d=a*b+c
echo $d
```

And will be called up something like this.

```
./script.sh < input.in
```

Now I have done a bit of digging and I have tried doing a simple.

```
./script.sh < input.in
```

such that it returns the answer 170

but this doesn't work. After further digging, it seems that in the script in need to use the command "source" But I am unsure how to do it in this case.

Can it be done? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

From `help source`:

```
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
    entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
    If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
    when FILENAME is executed.

    Exit Status:
    Returns the status of the last command executed in FILENAME; fails if
    FILENAME cannot be read.
```

So, in the script, you only need to add this line:

```bash
source input.in
```

or this one (the POSIX version):

```bash
. input.in
```

To pass the input file at runtime, you use [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html):

```bash
source "$1"
```

```bash
. "$1"
```

Also note that `d=a*b+c` won't work unless `d` has the "integer" attribute:

```bash
declare -i d
d=a*b+c
```

or you use [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) to perform the operation:

```bash
d=$((a*b+c))
```

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source "$1"
d=$((a*b+c))
echo "$d"
```

```bash
$ ./script.sh input.in
170
```

Comment: Another idea would be to `read` the values of the variables in the script, and then to pass (on standard input) a file containing only those values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic operation. Just `source` or `.` a file name, and the result is as if those lines were included in your primary script.

The syntax is simply this:

```
source file_name
```

or

```
. file_name
```

There are some nuances, but that's more advanced. See `man bash | grep source` for more details.